# How to replace permissions and everything inside with icacls on Windows Server 2012?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows, windows-server-2012-r2, icacls

Using Windows Server 2012 R2 AND Windows Server 2008 R2.

I have a folder called `C:\temp\test` and I want to grant access to `SYSTEM` and a user and all files and subdirectories, and remove everthing else. I've tried this command but all the existing permissions remain:

Existing permissions are:

```
Access : NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl
         BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl
         BUILTIN\Users Allow  ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
         BUILTIN\Users Allow  AppendData
         BUILTIN\Users Allow  CreateFiles
         CREATOR OWNER Allow  268435456
```

I want to remove all ACLs except `SYSTEM`, and add `<DOMAIN>\<USER>`

I tried this command:

```
icacls c:\temp\test /grant:r <DOMAIN>\<USER>:(OI)(CI)F /t

processed file: c:\temp\test
Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

When I look at the permissions afterwards, the `<DOMAIN>\<USER>` has the correct permissions but all the others remain. I thought `/grant:r` replaced all the permissions? Do you know what command I need to run to remove all the other permissions?

Comment: This command does exactly what I want `cacls c:\temp\test /t /g <DOMAIN>\<USER>:F` but I've heard that icacls has superseded it, can someone show me the equivalent icacls version to produce the same behaviour?

Comment: `/grant:r` only removes existing explicit permissions, not inherited ones from the folder above.  You'd need to include `/inheritance:r` as well.

Comment: If CACLS does the job then there's no reason you can't use it, whether it's been deprecated or not.

Comment: @joeqwerty true but it feels so dirty. cacls itself even returns a message to use icacls, so there must be a very good reason. `NOTE: Cacls is now deprecated, please use Icacls.`

Comment: @joeqwerty `cacls.exe` can set the ACL's in the wrong order, potentially causing problems (I'll leave this as an exercise for the reader).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As mentionned is comments, you also have to use the `/inheritance:r` switch to remove inherited permissions.

`/grant:r` only removes explicit permissions.

```
icacls c:\temp\test /inheritance:r /grant:r <DOMAIN>\<USER>:(OI)(CI)F /T
```

To also grant `SYSTEM` :

```
icacls c:\temp\test /inheritance:r /grant:r <DOMAIN>\<USER>:(OI)(CI)F /grant:r SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)F /T
```

Answer (score 9):

The parameter `/grant:r` didn't work for me. I had to use `/reset` to revert permissions to inherintance only and then remove the inherited permissions. Don't forget to change subdirectories with `/t` flag.

Comment: Agreed.  Had to do reset alone, then do steps by @krisFR.